# The least integer value of $x$, which satisfy $|x| + |\frac{x}{x - 1}| = \frac{x^2}{|x - 1|}$, is...

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> **Question:**  The least integer value of $x$, which satisfy $|x| + |\frac{x}{x - 1}| = \frac{x^2}{|x - 1|}$, is...

MY ATTEMPT:

**Case 1:** Taking all the modulus positive and solving ...
**Case 2:** Taking all the modulus negative and solving...
**Case 3:** Taking different signs of different modulus at a time and solving...

But the Case 3 will arise to many different cases and this will take a lot of time to solve. So, definitely an alternate method is required. Please provide an efficient method to solve this question. Thank you!

*P.S.: The answer to this question is x=0*

> This is a new edit made 8 hours ago. Anyone who posted their answers before that are not wrong and not flawed. Their answer will satisfy this question: The least integer value of $x$, which satisfy $|x| + |\frac{x}{x + 1}| = \frac{x^2}{|x - 1|}$, is.... Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Try squaring both sides, getting the remaining absolute values onto one side, then squaring again and solving

Comment: Just a doubt @Seth. Wouldn't squaring remove the negative values of the modulus which are supposed to be considered

Comment: I'm fairly sure that if you are careful in how you solve it, it should give you multiple answers (such as how $x^2=1$ would have $x=1$ or $x=-1$)

Comment: If you are not very restricted in how you can solve this though, I would recommend just plotting both sides of the equation on desmos and seeing where they intersect

Comment: I just did this, and it looks like the solutions are 0, 0.618 (probably $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$), and $\infty$

Comment: I only see $4$ different cases:  $x \lt -1, -1 \lt x \leq 0, 0 \leq x \lt 1,\text{  and } 1 \lt x$.  It shouldn't be that hard to solve the equation in all four cases.  It might help to note that $0$ is a solution and then divide both sides of the equation by $|x|$.

Comment: Also @Seth. I don't think I want to use the desmos method. I need to know how to solve it on pen and paper. Furthermore, the answer you got is wrong.

Comment: You say the answer is zero, ras, and that's also what you'd conclude from the comment by @Seth, since zero is the only integer solution Seth found. So, why do you say the answer Seth got is wrong, when it's the same as what you say the answer is?

Comment: Sorry@Seth. Did not see the 0 in your solution properly. Then he is right. But still want to solve on pen and paper without graphs on desmos

Comment: Thanks @GerryMyerson

Comment: The way to do it with pen and paper is in the comment from @RobertShore

Comment: "But the Case 3 will arise to many different cases" no it wont.   $x- 1 < x$ and $\frac x{x-1} = x \times \frac 1{x-1}$ so the only case you have is $x-1 < 0 < x$ and $\frac x{x-1} < 0$.  That's only one case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easier solution and a more analytical solution using the property of modulus:

$$|x| + |\frac{x}{x - 1}|=\frac{x^2}{|x - 1|}$$
$$\text{As, } |a| + |b| = |a + b| \text{ only, when } ab \geq 0$$
$$\text{and } |x| + |\frac{x}{x - 1}| = |x + \frac{x}{x - 1}|$$ is true only, if $x\cdot \frac{x}{x-1} \geq 0$
$$\implies x\in {0} \cup (1, \infty)$$
$\therefore$ Least value of x = 0

Comment: But the problem statement has $|x/(x+1)|$, not $|x/(x-1)|$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, the OP has changed the problem.  This is somewhat problematic, since the original problem, with $|x/(x+1)|$ instead of $|x/(x-1)|$ got two answers yesterday, and the new version has received two answers today. (I would recommend the OP edit their question to include a note that they changed the problem, and also notify yesterday's answerers with a comment to that effect beneath their answers.)

Comment: @Barry, at the time OP posted this answer, the question still had $x+1$ in it. OP edited the question to $x-1$ several hours after posting this answer. You're surely right that OP should be more transparent and communicative.

Comment: And in any event the solution OP has posted here is seriously flawed.

Comment: No@GerryMyerson this is the original solution from the person who created this question. How is it flawed. And yeah sorry for not being communicative.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, yes, I saw the perplexing time line in the answer and edit, but figured the OP came back and made the edit as an afterthought, maybe after reading your comment here.  Sorry I didn't make that clear. But also, what is the serious flaw in the OP's solution? I only see a missing "$\ge0$" in "$x\cdot{x\over x-1}\ge0$" before the final implication.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the most efficient way of doing it, but in my opinion it is more fun
$$|x|+\frac{|x|}{|x+1|}=\frac{x^2}{|x-1|}$$
$$x^2+\frac{x^2}{(x+1)^2}+\frac{2x^2}{|x+1|}=\frac{x^4}{(x-1)^2}$$
So clearly $x=0$ is a solution. Taking out a factor of $x^2$, we get
$$1+\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}+\frac{2}{|x+1|}=\frac{x^2}{(x-1)^2}$$
$$\frac{x^2}{(x-1)^2}-\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}-1=\frac{2}{|x+1|}$$
$$\frac{x^4}{(x-1)^4}+\frac{1}{(x+1)^4}+1-\frac{x^2}{(x-1)^2(x+1)^2}-\frac{x^2}{(x-1)^2}+\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}=\frac{4}{(x+1)^2}$$
$$\frac{3}{(x+1)^2}=\frac{x^4(x+1)^4+(x-1)^4+(x+1)^4(x-1)^4-x^2(x+1)^2(x-1)^2-x^2(x-1)^2(x+1)^4}{(x-1)^4(x+1)^4}$$
So if we say $x\neq-1,1$, we can multiply through by $(x+1)^4(x-1)^4$:

$$3(x-1)^4(x+1)^2=x^4(x+1)^4+(x-1)^4+(x+1)^4(x-1)^4-x^2(x+1)^2(x-1)^2-x^2(x-1)^2(x+1)^4$$
So it will be the solutions of this polynomial except for $x=1,-1$

Comment: Please let me know if i stuffed up my algebra

Comment: And how do you propose to solve this 8th degree equation?

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left\lvert #1 \right\rvert}$
Away from $x\in \{-1,0,1\}$ it suffices to find the solutions of $f(x)=0$, where
$$f(x)\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\abs{x^2+x}-\abs{x^2-1}-\abs{x-1}\text{.}$$
As stated in the comments, there are four cases to work through:
$$f(x)=2\cdot
\begin{cases}
x & x < -1 \\
-1 & -1 < x < 0 \\
x^2 + x -1 & 0 < x < 1 \\
1 & 1 < x
\end{cases}\text{.}$$
But this case analysis shows that $f$ is nondecreasing and has exactly one root, in the interval $(0,1)$. Therefore the only integral solution of the original equation is the trivial one at $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $0$ is a solution, the least integer solution has to be $\le0$, so $|x|=-x$ and $|x-1|=1-x$.
Thus the equation becomes
$$
-x-\frac{x}{1-x}=\frac{x^2}{1-x}
$$
that is
$$
-x+x^2-x=x^2
$$
Hence $x=0$ is the only solution $\le0$.

Answer (score 0):

Case $3$ is not as many cases as you'd think.

Consider.

Case 1: $x \ge 1$ then $x - 1 \ge 0$ and and the modulus are non-negitive.  However $\frac x{x-1}$ is undefined for $x = 1$ so $x> 1$

$x + \frac x{x-1} = \frac {x(x-1) + x}{x-1} = \frac {x^2}{x-1}$ which is always true so $x > 1$ are solutions.

Case 2: $x \le 0$ so $x -1 < 0$ but $\frac {x}{x-1} \ge  0$.

So $-x + \frac x{x-1} = - \frac {x^2}{x-1}$ which is always true if

$\frac {-x(x-1) + x}{x-1} = \frac {-x^2 + 2x}{x-1} = \frac {-x^2}{x-1}$ which only happens if so $x = 0$.  So $x = 0$ is   solution.

Case 3: $0 < x < 1$ then $x > 0$ and $x-1 < 0$ and $\frac x{x-1} < 0$.

So we want $x - \frac x{x-1} = -\frac {x^2}{x-1}$ which is true if

$\frac {x(x-1) - x}{x-1} = \frac {-x^2}{x-1}$ which is true if

$\frac {x^2 - 2x}{x-1} = \frac {-x^2}{x-1}$ which is true if and only if

$x^2 - 2x = -x^2$

$2x^2 = 2x$

$x^2 = x$ which happens if $x = 0$ or $x =1$ but those are out of range.

So solutions are $x= 0$ or $x > 1$.

Comment: Since $x=0$ is clearly a solution, and OP asks for the smallest (integer) solution, your Cases 1 and 3 aren't needed.

Comment: Yeah.  You're right....

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:
$$|x| + |\frac{x}{x - 1}| = \frac{x^2}{|x - 1|} \iff \\
|x|\left(1+\frac{1}{|x-1|}\right)=\frac{|x|^2}{|x-1|} \iff \\
1) \ |x|=0 \ \ \text{or} \ \ 2) \ 1+\frac1{|x-1|}=\frac{|x|}{|x-1|} \iff \\
1) \ x=0;\\
2) \ \frac{|x-1|+1}{|x-1|}=\frac{|x|}{|x-1|} \stackrel{x\ne 1}{\Rightarrow} \\
|x-1|=|x|-1 \Rightarrow x> 1.$$
Hence, the solution of the original equation is $x\in \{0\}\cup (1,+\infty)$ and the least integer solution is $x=0$.